# Basic auth using retrofit in Flutter

Tags: flutter, retrofit, basic-authentication

I have a project to build an app in Flutter and I have to login using Basic Auth and retrofit for the Api requests. I have searched everywhere and I haven't found anything that can help me on how to combine these two.  Nothing that I've done so far was succesful. Can anyone help me or show me documentation that can help me?

**UPDATE**

Should it be something like this?
Disclaimer: inside the http I don'thave a body or params and it should be a get request

```
@RestApi(baseUrl: '...')
abstract class ApiService {

  var basicAuth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode(username+":"+password));

  var response = await http.get(

       Uri.parse('...'),       
       headers: <String, String> {
      'authorization': basicAuth,
      'Accept':'application/json', 
      'contentType': 'application/json'},
     );

     print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
     print('Response body: ${response.body}');
   }

   //Login Service
   @GET('...')
   @FormUrlEncoded()
   Future<User> login();
```

Comment: There is a Flutter package called ``retrofit``. Add it to your project and make a request to the API endpoint with the basic auth. What's the problem.

Comment: you can use this `local_auth: ^2.1.2` package for local authentication

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I've already done that but maybe I don't do right the calling. Can you please show me an example? Sorry, I'm very new to all this. @OMiShah

Answer (score 0):

In Android We can do Basic auth like this:

```
// concatenate username and password with colon for authentication
        String credentials = username + ":" + password;
        // create Base64 encodet string
        final String basic =
                "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Authorization", basic);
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            }
        });
```

so maybe possible we can do like this also in flutter

```
var auth = 'Basic '+base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));

Future<Response> callAPI(param) async {
await dio.post('/api/test',
    data: {'param': param},
    options: Options(headers: <String, String>{'authorization': auth}));
```

}

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I've already tried this code for basic auth but maybe I'm doing something wrong when I connect it with the package retrofit. I've updated my code can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for basic request for auth.And if you want to return response, you can use something else instead of void. Like String or dynamic for return response

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' // import this

Future<void> sendRequest (dynamic baseUrl...)async{
 var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(baseUrl).replace(queryParameters: queryParameters),
      headers: header,
      body: json ?? jsonEncode(request),
    );
}
```